# How do I let users view or edit their form entries after submission in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

On my website I want the users to register and fill out a job application form using the Cognito Forms plugin.

While this works fine, I would like the users to be able to edit their job applications after submission if they want to update their qualifications, experience, mobile number, etc.  Is this possible, and if so, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

We are working on adding support for anonymously viewing and editing entries following submission, either by the users that are submitting the data initially or by anyone sent special view or edit links by entry administrators.

Please upvote or comment on this feature on our Idea Board: [Save & Resume](https://trello.com/c/Bk6swilY)

The key features will be:

1. The option to allow users who are filling out forms to request to save their work in progress, which will send them a link via email to resume their work later
2. The ability to control when view and edit links are valid based on conditions specified based on entry data.  For example, you could indicate that an edit link would remain valid even after the entry was submitted, but would not longer work once an internal only field was marked as processed by an administrator.
3. The ability to share entries through entry administration to provide view/edit links to anyone for any reason.